# fullCalendar resets after nextMonth view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, fullcalendar

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var date = new Date();

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title'
        //right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },

    defaultDate: new Date(),
    editable: true,
    events: [],
    firstDay: 6,
    //eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    dayClick: function (date,allDay,jsEvent,view) {

        var findByClass = $('.week-highlight');
        if (findByClass.length < 1) {

            $(this).parent().addClass('week-highlight');

            var e = $('<div></div>'); //element
            var cal = $('#calendarContainer').append(e);
            e.attr('id','myCalendar');

            //Open second Calendar if week selected on 1st calendar
            $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title'
                    //right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                },
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                editable: false,
                //events: [],
                firstDay: 6,
                events: function () {
                    var fetchDate; 

                    var clickedDate = $('#calendar').on('click','.fc-day,.fc-day-number',function(e){
                        e.stopPropagation();  
                        fetchDate = $(this).data("date");
                        var thisDate = $('#myCalendar').find(".fc-day[data-date='"+fetchDate+"']");

                        //add id for each td on $(#myCalenda), then thisDate parent parent ...
                        thisDate.addClass('disabled');
                        thisDate.parent().addClass('disabled');

                        console.log(fetchDate);
                        console.log(thisDate);
                    });
                    //fetchDate is undefined here must move to clickedDate...
                },
                //fallBack to previous calendar
                dayClick: function (date,allDay,jsEvent,view) {
                    var findByClass = $('.week-highlight1');

                    // is this the GODDAMN DISABLED WEEK?!?!!!!!11o1111o
                    if ($(this).closest("tr").hasClass("disabled")) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (findByClass.length < 1) {
                        $(this).parent().addClass('week-highlight1');
                    }
                    else {
                        findByClass.attr('class','');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            findByClass.attr('class',' ');
            $('#myCalendar').detach();
        }
    }
});
```

});

My HTML just have 
`<div id='calendar'></div>
    <div id="calendarContainer">
    </div>`

Im using fullCalendar and my issue here is when click into a date it will 'highlight' the whole week, referent to that day but when i click to see the next month and i come back to the month that had the 'highlighted' week (the calender resets clears all added classes). anyway to save the state of that row ?! or maybe adding it to events ?!
i dont know if i made myself clear but thnkz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the same code into viewRender, not just dayClick, so that when you switch views, your highlighting state is maintained.